# Matriz transposta que recebe valores não inteiros e fracionários

Tags: c, array, matriz

Estou resolvendo um exercício onde digito valores para uma matriz `3x3`, a imprimo e também exibo a sua transposta. O problema é que não estou conseguindo receber valores fracionários, e números com vírgula.

O código que consegui desenvolver é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void imprime_matriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
          printf("  %2d ",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void preenche_matriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf(" %d ",&matriz[i][j]);
        }

    }

}

void transposta(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i,j;
    int aux[3][3];

     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            aux[i][j] = matriz[j][i];

        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            matriz [i][j] = aux[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   int matriz[3][3];

    printf("\nDigite os elementos da Matriz:\n\n");
    preenche_matriz(matriz);

    imprime_matriz(matriz);

    transposta(matriz);
        printf("\n");
    imprime_matriz(matriz);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendendo "valores fracionários" como números reais então é porque você declarou que sua matriz é de números inteiros. Tente declarar sua matriz como float ou double e não int.

Comment: Atente também que a transposta de uma matriz x[M][N] é uma matriz xt[M][N] com M e N quaisquer, podendo ou não ser iguais, e que portanto você só poderá sobrescrever a matriz original com a transposta no caso particular de M igual a N.

Answer (score 0):

Declare sua matriz como float ou double! Para imprimir um double você deve usar "%lf" e para imprimir um float, "%f". Espero ter ajudado!